# SQL - Joining / lookup tables based on other tables' values, with range comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am going to query 3 tables by comparing the date value, with "greater" or "less than" conditions. But I fail to write a SQL about this. The table for date comparison has only a field instead of a range of 2 dates, i.e. start and end dates. The tables are:

staff_roster - major table containing staff's daily records of a month:

```
staff_no | store |  r_date
----------------------------
sf001    |   A   | 1/10/2016
sf001    |   A   | 2/10/2016
sf001    |   A   | 3/10/2016
sf001    |   A   | 4/10/2016
sf001    |   A   | 5/10/2016
sf001    |   A   | 6/10/2016
sf001    |   A   | 7/10/2016
sf001    |   A   | 8/10/2016
  ....
sf002    |   A   | 1/10/2016
sf002    |   A   | 2/10/2016
  ....
```

staff_posmove - the table in which the conditions look for:

```
staff_no |    p_date    | previous_pos | new_pos
---------------------------------------------------
sf001    |  3/10/2016   | Jr sales     | clerk
sf001    |  6/10/2016   | clerk        | Sr sales
```

staff_profile

```
staff_no | position 
---------------------
sf001    | Sr sales 
sf002    | Jr sales
```

I would like to get a result having columns of table "staff_roster" with an additional column "position", of which values depend on the other 2 tables.

The logic is: It compares each staff_roster.r_date to "p_date" of table "staff_posmove". If system finds same staff having a "r_date" smaller than "p_date", the value of "position" will be "previous_pos"; but if it is equal or greater, it will take "new_pos" as the value.

But the problem is there may be several records in "staff_posmove", and this makes duplicated and wrong results, since obviously there are overlapping conditions.

Take sf001 as example, my expected result is:

```
staff_no | store |   r_date  | position
-----------------------------------------
sf001    |   A   | 1/10/2016 | Jr sales
sf001    |   A   | 2/10/2016 | Jr sales
sf001    |   A   | 3/10/2016 | clerk
sf001    |   A   | 4/10/2016 | clerk
sf001    |   A   | 5/10/2016 | clerk
sf001    |   A   | 6/10/2016 | Sr sales
sf001    |   A   | 7/10/2016 | Sr sales
sf001    |   A   | 8/10/2016 | Sr sales
 ....
```

Additionally, if system does not find a record in "staff_posmove" of a staff for comparison, the "position" should lookup the table "staff_profile", putting relevant staff's position in the result "position":

```
staff_no | store |   r_date  | position
-----------------------------------------
sf002    |   A   | 1/10/2016 | Jr sales
sf002    |   A   | 2/10/2016 | Jr sales
 ....
```

I tried something like "CASE WHEN a.staff_no = b.staff_no AND a.r_date < b.p_date THEN CAST(b.previous_pos As varchar(10))" but still get wrong results. Question may be a bit long, but hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to solve this problem is to use `OUTER APPLY`.  This is made harder, because you don't have the *first* record -- the `staff_posmove` is missing the initial record.

To solve this, the following always considers the first record for each staff member, and then uses logic in the `select` to choose the position:

```
select r.*,
       (case when pm.p_date < r_date then pm.new_pos else pm.old_pos end) as position
from staff_roster r outer apply
     (select top 1 pm.*
      from (select pm.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by staff_no order by p_date) as seqnum
            from staff_posmove pm
           ) pm
      where p_date < r_date or seqnum = 1  -- always ensure first row is considered
      order by pm.p_date desc
     ) pm
```

Comment: It works! Thanks and I will study the detail of this statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested:

The below should give the first move after each roster (and hence we take previous job):

```
Select
r.staff_no, r.store_, r.r_date, p.previous_job
from staff_roster r left join staff_posmove p 
on p.staff_no = r.staff_no and r_date < p_date 
where row_number() over (partition by r.staff_no, r_date order by p_date) =1
```

And we add staff_profile to it to take the remaining ones as below:

```
Select
p.staff_no, r.store_, r.r_date, nvl(m.previous_job,p.position)
from staff_profile p join staff_roster r
on p.staff_no = r.staff_no
left join staff_posmove m
on m.staff_no = r.staff_no and r.r_date < m.p_date 
where row_number() over (partition by r.staff_no, r.r_date order by m.p_date) =1
```

Comment: I just have a try on it by editing a bit of the statement, e.g. nvl -> isnull for SQL server. Error occurs for the WHERE clauses: "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses".